# Is anything different in a New Game plus?

Tags: mass-effect-infiltrator

In Mass Effect: Infiltrator, I finished all of the levels and got the option to start a New Game+, which started the game over with everything I had purchased still available. Is there any difference between doing this and simply replaying each level?

Answer (score 3):

The difference from New Game+ is exactly as you mention, that you keep your upgrades.  This makes a run through on New Game+ easier.