# Can I earn the "Cerberus Escapees"  war asset more than once?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-infiltrator

Completing *Mass Effect: Infiltrator* once unlocks "1 Cerberus Escapees" according to the Galaxy at War screen, which equates to 40 War Assets inside *Mass Effect 3* proper.

*Mass Effect: Infiltrator*'s New Game+ unlocks, but it seems to be equivalent to just picking missions from the level selector, as your progress doesn't seem to save (no "resume/continue playing" option). However, any computers hacked and safes opened remain hacked and opened, and your skill unlocks and weapons carry over.

Skipping right to the end and beating the final boss again doesn't seem to unlock more Cerberus Escapees, but is there a way that I'm missing, or is it just a one-time thing?

Comment: is this the App version of ME3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is anything different in a New Game plus?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56814/is-anything-different-in-a-new-game-plus)

Comment: @murgatroid99 that post doesn't reference/answer whether/how you can get a second war asset

Comment: @BenBrocka I know it doesn't mention that in particular, but my question asks what the difference is between playing through a new game+ and replaying levels, and whether you get a second war asset should be a subset of that.

Comment: @Paralytic it's a different game, an iOS game that ties into ME3's system

Comment: @murgatroid99 I disagree. They look like two different, although possibly related, questions.

Comment: Pretty sure it's one-time. I am just not sure whether the same war asset carries across multiple playthroughs of ME3...

Comment: @JamesJiao That one I can confirm - the war asset is permanently linked to your ME3, like your promoted multiplayer characters.  I earned it on my first playthrough, and it's still there on my second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can earn Cerberus Escapees (the war asset from playing *Mass Effect: Infiltrator*) **three times**:

- For finishing the game (once)
- For getting gold on all Main Story checkpoints
- For getting gold on all Turian Story checkpoints

Each is worth 40 TMS in war assets, for a **total of 120 TMS**.<sup>[1](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-General-Discussion-No-ME3-Spoilers-allowed/Does-the-Cerberus-Escapees-War-Asset-in-Mass-Effect-Infiltrator-cap-out-at-3-11345146-1.html#11350889)</sup> It will show on all *ME3* save games linked to your Origin account.